# ¿Se puede retornar un observable dentro de otro observable? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs

buenas noches. Mi problemas es el siguiente, necesito devolver un observable (HttpClient de Angular), pero antes me he suscrito a otro observable, dejo el código abajo.

```
export class MessagesService {

  constructor( private _Salas: SalasService, private _HTTP: HttpClient) {}

  getAll(FakeID) {

    this._Salas.getRealID(FakeID).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.length >= 1) {
        return this._HTTP.get(`http://localhost/api/chat/obtener-mensajes/${resp[0].MessagesID}`);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Como se puede apreciar dependo de la información del observable padre, dejo el código del servicio.

```
export class SalasService {

  private SalasDataS = new BehaviorSubject([]);


  constructor( private _HTTP: HttpClient ) {
    this._HTTP.get('http://localhost/api/usuario/salas').pipe(
      map( resp => resp.Data.Salas )
    ).subscribe( resp => {
      // Dato inicial
      this.SalasDataS.next(resp);
    });

  }

  getAll() {
    return this.SalasDataS.asObservable();
  }

  getRealID(FakeID) {
    return this.getAll().pipe(
      map( item => item.filter( response => {if (response.DisplayID === FakeID) { return response; }}))
    );

  }

}
```

Todo funciona correctamente, ya lo he comprobado individualmente, mi único problema es al intentar devolver el observable y suscribirme a el, como en el sig. código:

```
export class ContentMessagesComponent {

  constructor( private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _Messages: MessagesService ) {

     this._route.params.subscribe(resp => {

      this._Messages.getAll(resp.id).subscribe( resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });

    });

  }

}
```

Al ejecutar el método 'getAll' del MessagesService Angular me manda este error por consola
[image: Error por consola]

Perdonen por el código o lo errores de TypeScript apenas estoy aprendiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el método getAll no está devolviendo nada. El código de ese método:

```
getAll(FakeID) {
  this._Salas.getRealID(FakeID).subscribe(resp => {
    if (resp.length >= 1) {
      return this._HTTP.get(`http://localhost/api/chat/obtener-mensajes/${resp[0].MessagesID}`);
    }
  });
}
```

es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
getAll(FakeID) {
  let pideDatos = resp => {
    if (resp.length >= 1) {
      return this._HTTP.get(`http://localhost/api/chat/obtener-mensajes/${resp[0].MessagesID}`);
    }
  };

  this._Salas.getRealID(FakeID).subscribe(pideDatos);
}
```

Lo que devuelva la función pideDatos es ignorado. La solución es encadenar los Observables, usando el operador flatMap, y devolver todo:

```
getAll(FakeID) {
   return this._Salas.getRealID(FakeID).pipe(
     flatMap(resp => {
       if (resp.length) {
         return this._HTTP.get(`http://localhost/api/chat/obtener-mensajes/${resp[0].MessagesID}`);
       }
       return of(null);
     })
   );
}
```

Comment: WOW, muchas gracias, ya funciono. Un saludo. :]